# Journalist who visits an isolationist America

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this back in the 80s, I think. It's a short story about a person, maybe a journalist, from Europe coming to the US to get an understanding of the American people and culture after the US has isolated itself from any kind of interaction with other countries. The journalist stays with the family of an officer of the military and comments on the differences between his world view and the world view of a typical American family. The daughter of the officer may have come to his room one night, and he's not sure how to respond. At the end of the story, he begins his journey home, still without a strong sense of what America believes.

Psychological SF in the manner of Clifford Simak, maybe. I remember reading it in one of the anthologies of SF that came out in the 70s or 80s.

Comment: A detail - does his bedroom have a wall-sized video screen, and one night he has it show a forest fire?

Comment: Coming Attraction is another story that I've read. Interesting that it came up from my inquiry, but it's not the one I have in mind. In the story I'm thinking of, the protagonist is from Europe (England, I think) and has conversations about how the US has essentially shut itself off from the rest of the world and is therefore a cultural backwater, it's citizenry concerned mostly with just the survival of America. When the daughter is forward with him, he's unsure of how to respond and finds the incident ironic considering the otherwise very conservative culture. Not much to go on, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be referring to *[Coming Attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coming_Attraction)* by Fritz Leiber. It's not exactly as you describe but the protagonist is British and visiting a post-limited-nuclear war USA.

He does meet a girl but she has...issues.

It ends with the protagonist wishing he could go

> to wait for the rusty ship that would take me back over the seas to England.

Comment: Maybe it's Leiber's *other* story about a British visitor to a "dystopian" future America. I think I'll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a perfect match, because the U.S. is not "isolationist": still in a cold war with the Commies, still fighting in Southeast Asia (Siam), still has a Peace Corps. And the British visitor is a poetry professor, similar but not exactly the same thing as a journalist. But I think you may be thinking of [Fritz Leiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Leiber)'s 1970 short story ["America the Beautiful"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57260). Does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?57260) ring a bell?

Here is a review from [The PorPor Books Blog](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/):

> Fritz Leiber’s ‘America the Beautiful’ sees a young British academic traveling to a United States that seems like something out of Tomorrowland; hypersonic shuttles from London to Dallas, automated cars and freeways, plenty of clean, cheap energy, social and racial harmony, etc., etc. But there’s an undercurrent of unease…something about The Commies (!?)…the story comes across as a limp effort at political commentary, and confirms my belief that [Leiber] was one of the more overrated authors of his day.

Here are the opening paragraphs of the story:

> I am returning to England. I am shorthanding this, July 5, 2000, aboard the Dallas-London rocket as it arches silently out of the diffused violet daylight of the stratosphere into the eternally star-spangled purpling night of the ionosphere.
>
> I have refused the semester instructorship in poetry at UTD, which would have munificently padded my honorarium for delivering the Lanier Lectures and made me for four months second only to the Poet in Residence.
>
> And I am almost certain that I have lost Emily, although we plan to meet in London in a fortnight if she can wangle the stopover on her way to take up her Peace Corps command in Niger.
>
> I am not leaving America because of the threat of a big war. I believe that this new threat, like all the rest, is only another move, even if a long and menacing queen's move, in the game of world politics, while the little wars go endlessly on in Chad, Czechoslovakia, Sumatra, Siam, Baluchistan, and Bolivia as America and the Communist League firm their power boundaries.

**The journalist stays with the family of an officer of the military**

> The purity of the atmosphere was strikingly brought to my notice when I debarked at Dallas rocketport and found the Grissims waiting for me outdoors, downwind of the landing area. They made a striking group, all of them tall, as they stood poised yet familiarly together: the professor with his grizzled hair still close-trimmed in military fashion, for he had served almost as long as a line officer and in space services as he had now as a university physicist; his slim, white-haired wife; Emily, like her mother in the classic high-waisted, long-skirted Directoire style currently fashionable; and her brother Jack, in his dress pale grays with sergeant's stripes, on furlough from Siam.

**and comments on the differences between his world view and the world view of a typical American family.**

> In particular, I argued that many or most Americans were motivated by a subtle, even sophisticated puritanism, which made them feel that the world was not safe unless they were its moral arbiters, and that this puritanism was ultimately based on the same swollen concern about property and money—industry, in its moral sense—that one found in the Swiss and Scottish Presbyterians and most of the early Protestants.

**The daughter of the officer may have come to his room one night, and he's not sure how to respond.**

> She did not come into my room, but after a pause during which I sat up jerkily and she became again a shadow, she beckoned to me.
>
> I snatched up my dressing gown and followed her as she moved noiselessly down the hall. My throat was dry and constricted, my heart was pounding a little, with apprehension as well as excitement. I realized that despite my near week with the Grissims, a part of my mind was still thinking of the professor and his wife as a strait-laced colonel and his lady from a century ago, when so many retired army officers Lived in villas around San Antonio, as they do now around the Dallas-Ft. Worth metropolitan area.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "You still think I'm a puritan, don't you?" she softly asked me afterward, smiling at me sideways with the smeared remains of her crimson mouth, her gray eyes enigmatic blurs of shadow.
>
> "Yes, I do," I told her forthrightly. "The puritan playing the hetaera, but still the puritan."